# Embedded YouTube videos are not working on the WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, plugins, lazy-loading

I am trying to add a YouTube video to a post on my WordPress Website. Unfortunately, when I am trying to play the video, I get the error "**ReferenceError: perfmattersLazyLoadYouTube is not defined
at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):640)"**.

[image: Error image]

I understand that it must be something wrong with the Perfmatters plugin, but I enabled lazy loading for iframe and videos.

[image: Perfmatters settings]

What can be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developers of the Perfmatters plugin yet? If not it might be a good idea to do so, they should be able to help you out with this: https://perfmatters.io/contact/

Comment: I am gonna try, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred because both plugins: WP-Rocket and Perfmatters, were conflicting. Both of them were trying to lazy-load iframes and videos. When I disabled iframes/video and YouTube preview in the plugin Prefmatters it solved the issue.